# libgdx - group transformation

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm new in LibGDX. 
I created group with actors in show method and add listener (where i calculate rotation matrix) and want to rotate all actors from group with batch.setTransformMatrix(matrixResult); but nothing happens. How can I force to rotate all actors of group?

```
 @Override
   public void show() {
      camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
      camera.position.set(0f, 0f, - 120);
      camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
      camera.near = 0.1f;
      camera.far = 300f;

      camera.update();
      stage = new Stage();
      shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
      myBatch = new SpriteBatch();
      shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
      sphere = BuildSphere(5, 100);
      group = new Group(){
         @Override
         public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            batch.setTransformMatrix(matrixResult);
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

         }
      };

      group.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
      group.addListener(new InputListener(){

         @Override
         public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
               int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("MOUSE_X_BEG", Float.toString(x));
            Gdx.app.log("MOUSE_Y_BEG", Float.toString(y));
            begX = x;
            begY = y;
            return true;
         }
         @Override
         public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
               int pointer) {
            endX = x;
            endY = y;
            //isRotate = true;
            float translationX = endX-begX;
            float translationY = begY-endY;
            float length = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(translationX,2) + Math.pow(translationY,2));
            Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            if(length>0){
               if(begX-endX == 0){
                  axis.x = 1;
               }else{
                  float angle = (float) (Math.atan(translationY/translationX) + Math.PI/2.0*(translationX <0 ? -1 : 1));
                  axis.z = 1;
                  axis.x = (float) Math.cos(angle);
                  axis.y = (float) Math.sin(angle);
               }
            }
            quaternion = new Quaternion(axis, 0.02f*length);
            Matrix4 rotation = new Matrix4(quaternion);
            matrixResult = rotation.mul(matrixRotationOld);
            matrixRotationOld = matrixResult;


         }


      });
      //group.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
      for (CenterCoordinate cenCoordinate : sphere.getPolygonCenterCoordinates()) {
         Vector3 vector = cenCoordinate.getCartesianCenter();
         Polygon polygon = new Polygon(1, cenCoordinate.getType().getCode(), cenCoordinate.getRadius(), cenCoordinate.getPsi(),
               cenCoordinate.getKsi(), vector, cenCoordinate.getRotation());

         group.addActor(polygon);
      }

      stage.addActor(group);
      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); 


   }
```

Polygon extends Actor draw method :

```
         @Override
  public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
     translation.setToTranslation(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
     matrix.mul(translation);
     shader.begin();
     shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", matrix);
     mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_LINE_LOOP, 1, mesh.getNumVertices()-1);
     shader.end();
     matrix.idt();

  }
```

Comment: Do you want to rotate all actors themselves, or the group? The difference is either rotate all actors individually, around their local origin, or do you want to rotate all actors around the groups origin?

Comment: I want to rotate the group with matrix rotation.

Comment: Well, when you you set the matrix on the batch, it will also affect all other groups. Furthermore I don't understand what you are doing here. Group actually is an actor and has something like setRotation. Why don't you just use that, but instead do some matrix multiplications?

Comment: I set matrix on the batch, but nothing happen. I draw half of sphere with hexagons and pentagons and I want to rotate sphere on touch. Sphere is my group. Polygons are my actors. I calculate matrix of rotation.

Comment: Are you using Stage for 3D? Then I don't understand why you have a SpriteBatch. Why are you talking about Sphere? Or do you mean circle?

Comment: I use PerspectiveCamera, and I want to get some pseudo 3D sphere - i calculate sphere coordinates after i translate it to cartesian and draw on camera with rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotating the `batch` will not rotate the `group`. If you want to `rotate` everything i would suggest to `rotate` the camera of the `Stage` and set the `Stage`s `SpriteBatch`s `ProjectionMatrix` to `cam.combined`. But to `rotate` only the `Group` use the `rotateBy(degrees)` or `setRotation(degrees)` method.
Rotating the `SpriteBatch` or the `camera` is actually only a change of the view, but rotating the `Actor` (in your case the `Group`) changes the logic of them.
In the `draw()` method you then will need to take care about this `rotation` and then you will have the result you want.

Comment: thank you, i solve the problem - i add my gloabal rotation first for polygon, before its own ratation and it is seems to work